# Action Controller: Exception Caught Sass::SyntaxError in Posts#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

I've been following the tutorial from here: http://railsinstallfest.org/guides/installfest41/finishing_a_basic_blog/

and I've run into this error:  `Action Controller: Exception Caught`

I've updated a number of files:

```
    app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:58
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in          `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3962393091843783815_70202089917300'
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

And I think I was tripped up somewhere around here:

Press n and then enter to skip overwriting our **application.html.erb** layout file. By skipping this we do miss out on some of Foundation’s responsive design features, but we’ve already added our RSS link to our layout file and allowing the install to overwrite our layout file would mean we’d lose that link. If you’re comfortable putting the autodiscovery link tag back into the new layout file, rerun the foundation install and allow it to overwrite your layout.

```
    app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:58  
        // This is the default html and body font-size for the base rem value.
        // $rem-base: 16px;

        // Allows the use of rem-calc() or lower-bound() in your settings
        Line 58: @import "foundation/functions";

        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in    `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3962393091843783815_70202089917300'

    Extracted source (around line #5):
    3<head>
    4  <title>QuickBlog</title>
    5  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-  turbolinks-track" => true %>
    6  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    7  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8  <%= auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, posts_path(:atom)) %>

    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `index'
    Extracted source (around line #10):
    8    def index
    9      @posts = Post.all
   10     respond_to do |format|
   11       format.html # index.html.erb
   12       format.json { render json: @posts }
   13       format.atom
```

I'm on a Mac OSX 10.9.5, Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.0.0p576

Answer (score 0):

On line 58 of the file app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss, it looks like it is:

```
@import "foundation/functions";
```

Can you try changing it to just:

```
@import "functions";
```

A server restart might help (if you haven't already done so) - sometimes it's necessary after adding a gem.

Comment: That gave me a different exception message.